# Reuse Data From Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm trying to reuse data from my service. Basically, I have two actions `index` and `show` books.

In index, I fetch all books (obviously) and show, as per usual, I only fetch a given record. But I also want to show related books and for that I'd like to reuse the data requested in the index action

my service is this:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('book', ['$http', '$q',
  function($http, $q) {

    var values = [];
    var book = {
      getAll: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/books.json'
      }).success(function(data, status){
        values = data;
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    get: function(id){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/books/' + id + '.json'
      })
    },
    getValues: function(){
      return values;
    }
  }
  return book;
}]);
```

and in my `ShowBookController` I'm calling this function:

```
getBook();
function getBook(){
  var promise = book.get(currentBook);
  promise.then(function(book){
    $scope.book = book.data[0];
  })
  console.log(book.getValues())
}
```

But console.log prints an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could move `console.log(book.getValues())` inside then callback because get is an asyncrhonous api call.

I hope that helps